# "Input string was not in a correct format" error in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script in which after 4 hours, bonus level must be appeared in main menu. even facing an error, it worked fine in unity editor but after playing in mobile, it doesn't work. here is my script;

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Date : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Start is called before the first frame update
     DateTime currentDate;
     DateTime oldDate;
     public static bool bonus;

     void Start()
     {
         //Store the current time when it starts
         currentDate = System.DateTime.Now;
 
         //Grab the old time from the player prefs as a long
         long temp = Convert.ToInt64(PlayerPrefs.GetString("sysString"));
 
         //Convert the old time from binary to a DataTime variable
         DateTime oldDate = DateTime.FromBinary(temp);
         print("oldDate: " + oldDate);
         TimeSpan difference = currentDate.Subtract(oldDate);
         if(difference.Hours>4){
            bonus=true;
            print ("Yes");
        }
        else{
            print ("No");
        }
     }
    
     void OnApplicationQuit()
     {
         //Savee the current system time as a string in the player prefs class
         PlayerPrefs.SetString("sysString", System.DateTime.Now.ToBinary().ToString());
 
     }   
}
```

here is the error;

```
formatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
System.Number.StringToNumber (System.String str, System.Globalization.NumberStyles options, System.Number+NumberBuffer& number, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info, System.Boolean parseDecimal) (at <d7ac571ca2d04b2f981d0d886fa067cf>:0)
System.Number.ParseInt64 (System.String value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles options, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo numfmt) (at <d7ac571ca2d04b2f981d0d886fa067cf>:0)
System.Int64.Parse (System.String s, System.IFormatProvider provider) (at <d7ac571ca2d04b2f981d0d886fa067cf>:0)
System.Convert.ToInt64 (System.String value) (at <d7ac571ca2d04b2f981d0d886fa067cf>:0)
Date.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/Date.cs:21)
```

Comment: Clearly the string doesn't [only] contain an integer. If there's anything other than the digits 0-9, it will fail. I recommend setting a breakpoint and debugging.

Comment: The number is being convert to an int instead of a long.  Use following : ((ulong)System.DateTime.Now.ToBinary()).ToString();

Comment: thanks for reply but it didn't work for me. You mean replacing PlayerPrefs.SetString("sysString", System.DateTime.Now.ToBinary().ToString()); by PlayerPrefs.SetString("sysString", ((ulong)System.DateTime.Now.ToBinary()).ToString());

Comment: The error is for the first time I play the game. there isn't any error after that. but when I use Clear All PlayerPrefs in Edit, the error again appears.

Comment: @jdweng why should something that returns a `long` be converted into an `int` if not explicitly cast? also `ulong` != `long`/`Int64`...

Comment: I tested with VS and was getting a negative number in the string output.  It appears the ToBinary() gave an integer.  the default type for a number in Net is an int.

Comment: The following works :             string now = ((ulong)System.DateTime.Now.ToBinary()).ToString();
            ulong temp = Convert.ToUInt64(now);
            DateTime oldDate = DateTime.FromBinary((long)temp);

Comment: sorry bro! Could you please write a complete code implementing yours and mine. I'm new to Unity

Answer (score 0):

> The error is for the first time I play the game. there isn't any error after that. but when I use Clear All PlayerPrefs in Edit, the error again appears

The issue is that in this case `PlayerPrefs.GetString` returns an **empty** string!

You should check this and perform your bonus check only if there was a valid string.

For further control I would also recommend to rather use [`long.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.int64.tryparse)

```
 void Start()
 {
     //Store the current time when it starts
     currentDate = System.DateTime.Now;

     var oldTimeString = PlayerPrefs.GetString("sysString", "");

     if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(oldTimeString))
     {
         //Grab the old time from the player prefs as a long
         if(long.TryParse(oldTimeString, out var temp)
         {
             //Convert the old time from binary to a DataTime variable
             var oldDate = DateTime.FromBinary(temp);
             print("oldDate: " + oldDate);
             var difference = currentDate.Subtract(oldDate);
             if(difference.Hours>4)
             {
                 bonus=true;
                 print ("Yes");
             }
             else
             {
                 print ("No");
             }
         }
         else
         {
             Debug.LogError($"Could not parse long out of given /"{oldTimeString}/"!", this);
         }
     }
     else
     {
         Debug.Log("First start -> No");
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Man! it worked for me! I set a default value for PlayerPrefs.GetString ("sysString","10"). It worked fine in Unity Editor without any error, But when I Play the game in mobile, It doesn't work. what's wrong?